# property of the Gelfand transform: why does an isometry map closed sets to closed sets?

Tags: general-topology, functional-analysis, operator-theory, banach-algebras

The following is a theorem about self-adjoint subalgebra of $C(X)$ where $X$ is compact Hausdorff and the first half of its proof:
[image]

Here are my **questions**:

> - Why $\Gamma:\mathfrak{U}\to C(M_{\mathfrak U})$ being an isometry implies that $\Gamma(\mathfrak{U})$ is closed in $C(M_{\mathfrak U})$?
> - Why does $\Gamma(\mathfrak{U})$ separate points?

---

Here $M_\mathfrak{U}$ denotes the set of non zero complex multiplicative linear functions on $\mathfrak{U}$.  For the second question, I think the book means $\Gamma(\mathfrak{U})$ separate points of $M_{\mathfrak U}$, which means for any two distinct points $x,y\in M_{\mathfrak U}$, $f(x)\neq f(y)$ for some $f\in \Gamma(\mathfrak{U})$. But I don't see how to give an argument.

Comment: Any isometry $h\colon X\to Y$ between complete metric spaces maps closed sets $F\subseteq X$ to closed sets: if $y_n\to y$ with $y_n\in h(F)$, say $y_n=h(x_n)$ with $x_n\in F$ then $(y_n)$ is Cauchy so $(x_n)$ is, so $x_n$ converges, say $x_n\to x$, so $x\in F$ because $F$ is closed, so $y=h(x)$ so $y\in h(F)$.

Comment: @EricWofsey: I thought it is a standard notation. $M_{\mathfrak U}$ denotes the set of non zero complex multiplicative linear function on $\mathfrak{U}$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Gro-Tsen commented, the fact that $\Gamma$ is an isometry implies its image is closed because $\mathfrak{U}$ is a complete metric space (since it is closed in $C(X)$).  Any subset of a metric space that is complete as a metric space is automatically closed, since a sequence that converged to a point outside the set would be a Cauchy sequence with no limit in the set.

The fact that $\Gamma(\mathfrak{U})$ separates points comes from the fact that elements of $M_\mathfrak{U}$ are defined as functions on $\mathfrak{U}$.  That is, if $x,y\in M_\mathfrak{U}$ are distinct, there must be some $u\in \mathfrak{U}$ such that $x(u)\neq y(u)$.  But $x(u)=(\Gamma(u))(x)$ and similarly for $y$, so this just says that $\Gamma(u)$ separates $x$ from $y$.